# Turn DirectoryIterator into mappable array?

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I want to turn the list of directory contents into a JSON array in PHP (I'm very new to PHP). I know this works:

```
// this code works
$base_dir = './posts/';
$directory_iterator = new Directoryiterator($base_dir);
$file_array = [];
foreach($directory_iterator as $file) {
  if(!$file->isDot()) {
    $file_array[] = $file->getFilename();
  }
}
echo json_encode($file_array);
```

However, I thought it might be more concise to use aggregate functions (filter and then map) rather than iterating over it. I would imagine it would look something like this in JavaScript:

```
// this is what I'd imagine it looks like in JS
Array.from(directory_iterator)
  .filter(file => !file.isDot())
  .map(file => file.getFilename())
```

I tried using `iterator_to_array` to convert the iterator to an array to perform the aggregate functions on, then use `array_filter` and `array_map`, like so:

```
// this doesn't work
$file_array = array_map(
  function($file) { return $file->getFilename(); },
  array_filter(
    iterator_to_array($directory_iterator),
    function($file) { return !$file->isDot(); })
  );
```

but the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

When I run `var_dump($file->getFilename())` inside the `array_filter()` callback, it gives me `string(0) ""`. So I'm guessing the original iterator-to-array conversion was wrong.

---

What am I doing wrong here? Is `iterator_to_array()` not the correct function to transform the `DirectoryIterator` object into an array of the file objects within?

Secondly, are there map and filter functions that are methods of the array rather than taking an array as an argument, similar to in JavaScript? I think this would make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have nested folders, then you should use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) along with [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php). To skip dots use `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag. Then you can get paths like following:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . '/test/', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);

$paths = array_keys(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

Iterators are often recursive, so there are no native `map` and `filter` functions for them in PHP. To filter an iterator you can use [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) or [`RecursiveFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php).

Comment: This is cool! It would have taken me a long time to find classes like `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

Comment: I don't have nested folders, however. Is there any reason I can't use the (non-recursive) `DirectoryIterator` and `IteratorIterator` classes? Their names would suggest that they don't work fundamentally differently, but it doesn't seem to work with the non-recursive versions.

Comment: @JonathanLam, here is [the comment](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.filesystemiterator.php#114997) that describes the difference between `DirectoryIterator` and `FilesystemIterator`. Long story short, in this particular case you cannot use `DirectoryIterator` as it doesn't have flags to skip dots. Again can you guarantee that your folder will have only files in it, but not other folders too? If yes, you can use `FilesystemIterator` + `IteratorIterator` instead of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` + `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

Comment: thanks. Again, I think the likeness of names threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator_to_array() within the array_filter() function returns an array of DirectoryIterator objects. Then you are running array_map, which is trying to apply a function on each one of the DirectoryIterator object within that array. That's why you are getting an empty list.

Check out the following with 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator'.

```
// flattens the directory
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(new DirectoryIterator($dir));

// creates a map - file path as the key and SPLFileInfo as the value
$map = iterator_to_array($it);

// some array functions to use for example;
$filePaths = array_keys($map);

// returns an array of SPLFileInfo objects
$files = array_values($map)

// applies a function on each element in $map - modifies it
array_walk($map, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = $key . ' => ' . $value->getFilename();
});

// modified
var_dump($map);
```

You can use the array functions after that. I recommend using built in [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php). Look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
use RecursiveDirectoryIterator;
use SplFileInfo;

class DirectoryContentProvider implements DirectoryContentProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return SplFileInfo[]
     */
    public function getContent(string $path): array
    {
        $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
        $list = iterator_to_array($iterator);

        return array_reduce($list, function (array $carrier, SplFileInfo $file) {
            if ($file->isFile()) {
                $carrier[] = $file;
            }

            return $carrier;
        }, []);
    }
}
```